# how to do search by using Date and Time

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am working with a Codeigniter3 project where I saved data as an integer by using the following format

```
strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'))
```

Now, I want to fetch data from my database based on today's date which is not working.

I used following code for fetching today's record

```
select * from user where created=strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: use less than and greater than as `created >= strtotime(date('Y-m-d')."00:00")` AND  `created <= strtotime(date('Y-m-d')."23:59")`

Comment: It is best to store date and time in the appropriate field type. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are storing a unix timestamp - seconds from 1970 - so it will only match for exactly 1 second on the day you are after.

Ideally you would store the date in a format that (my)sql recognizes as a date format so that you can easily query the database.

With the unix timestamp you have now, you would need to [convert it to a DateTime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) format and get the [date part](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) of it.

In MySQL:

```
select * from user where DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(:your_timestamp))
```

Comment: jeroen, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) = my sql this as a string and return 0 value

Answer (score 1):

Try this-
`$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE created BETWEEN ".strtotime(date('Y-m-d').'00:00')." AND ".strtotime(date('Y-m-d').'23:59'));`

Comment: @surma Glad this helped. Kindly accept the answer. Happy Coding.

Comment: where to click to make it as an answer

Comment: @surma you're smart enough to figure it out. ;)